# Need help managing large files

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, file-io, linux-kernel

I want to read 4GB file & create a copy of it by making changes in some fields. My priority is time efficiency i.e. processing should be quick.
I want to load it into memory so that read/write operations become fast. I should use heap? Or should i try something else like memory mapped files? or any other way out?

First of all thank you everyone for contributing ... Let me reframe my question... Here you go..
I have to get a file from user, this file is about 3-4GB large. It contains records, each records have some fields which has some sensitive data which i need to search and encrypt it till the EOF..
If I perform searching and encryption with FILE I/O it will take forever.. as its batch processing...  So i can create an array of 4GB on heap as i am working on 64bit OS, load entire file and perform operation. this local copy will give better performance than that of FILE IO...
I am considering memory mapped files as it will eliminate need of array(local copy) & operation speed is also good, however i am not familiar with it so asking whethere is it advisable for above mentioned scenario... !!
I was also thinking of considering MATLAB... you can also suggest if you have a better way out .. thnx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be to go with a memory mapped approach, but you should really try it out and measure what gives the best performance for you. Begin with the naive straight forward implementation, and if that's not good enough, try to optimize it.

Comment: I second the memory-map approach.  It both one of the simplest and fastest, except for certain access patterns.  One should keep in mind that for successfully mapping a *whole* 4 GiB file, one needs a >32bit address size on the machine.  Partial mapping would resolve such limits if necessary.

Comment: Correct for a professional, but the questions seems to be the question of a beginner. Memory-mapped I/O requires some knowledge about the underlying system architecture.

Comment: @frunsi No, it doesn't require knowledge about the underlying system architecture.

Comment: @VJovic: Well, Linux is absolutely excellent when it comes to mmap'ed IO. And lets ignore other architrectures: But then, the details, that gory details. For our question, we really should start at the basics.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is straight-forward, but requires some more information from your side about the details of the given file format.

However, some pseudo-code for a universal solution (plain C, ask for a C++ implementation when want it):

```
#define BUFSIZE 4096 // 4k, try larger or smaller values to improve performance...

int process_file( const char* filename ) {
  char buffer[BUFSIZE];
  size_t nread;
  FILE* fp;
  if( (fp=fopen(filename,"rb"))==NULL ) return 1;
  while( (nread=fread(buffer,1,BUFSIZE,fp))>=0 ) {
    if( nread==0 ) break; // EOF
    process_file_buffer( buffer, nread );
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return nread>=0 ? 0 : 2; // 0==success, 2==read error, check "errno"!
}

void process_file_buffer( const char* buffer, size_t size ) {
  // process, and write result to target file
}
```

**EDIT**:

Regarding your memory management question doubts: It depends a lot on your actual code & your actual requirements. In my sample code there is just one single buffer, automatically allocated on stack, that is totally sufficient for that use-case.

However, if you have special requirements, then explicitely ask about them!

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

This code is solid and provides a perfect foundation for more. However: if you will ever experience performance problems, then you really have to run a profiler (or write & your own profiling code).

Why?

You may suspect that THIS CODE is the bottleneck, but I will bet that it will not be ;) Don't forget, that you also have to write something to DISK, and don't forget that you have to pass any single byte of the file through memory - and from there through the CPU registers - to process it (that was one of your actual requirements...).

SO: Don't mind about memory mapped IO yet. First you have to mind about anything else ;)

You probably do not like to hear that. But that just is your initial situation.

And, before you start thinking about memory management, you should start to think about your actual I..O.. requirements.

**YET ANOTHER EDIT:**

KISS - Keep It Simple, Stupid ;-)

Comment: You're allocating an array of BUFSIZE pointers, while I think you want chars? And you probably want to close the file when done.

Comment: +1 Loading part of the file and processing it makes it possible to do the processing parallel to the loading. Will be the most efficient solution in many cases.

Comment: @daramarak: Yes, after all this code will not astonish anyone who has some experience with similar tasks. But it works and it is very solid. BTW.. I should add something ...

Comment: @daramarak No, this is the worse suggestion, and not correct.

Comment: @VJovic for me it looks like a pragmatic approach. Especially earlier when nothing was known about the processing of the data this was a reasonable solution. If it is incorrect I beg you to point at the ways the code is wrong so it may be corrected. Just stating that a solution is worse and incorrect isn't constructive.

Answer (score 1):

From the description of your problem I'm not sure you can avoid poor I/O performance. If you have to scan through 4gb of data to get to the record you want and then write the whole file out again I doubt it will matter too much if you use normal file I/O or mmap as the bottle neck will be reading the data off the disk. In both cases the kernel will attempt to cache frequently accessed parts of the file so re-reads are fast.

It sounds like you want some sort of copy-on-write support from the file system but that would be highly dependant on the file-system features (if they exist at all).

You could try using mmap with MAP_PRIVATE. You would first mmap your source file into memory. Any changes made would be held in memory only (MAP_PRIVATE) but any un-touched parts of the file would be backed from the original file (reducing memory pressure if you don't touch it). You would then have to write out the new file with normal file I/O going through the mapped memory. However I doubt the kernel will be clever enough to spot any un-needed copying.

As others have pointed out for files of this size a 64 bit architecture would be needed to map the whole file at once.